# C# Hacer un output de 2 columnas de 2 arreglos diferentes

Tags: c#

Si tengo esto

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList() { "A", "A", "A" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList() { "B", "B", "B", "B" };
```

es posible lograr algo como esto de output

```
            A         B
            A         B    
            A         B
                      B
```

En un principio lo pense obviamente con FOR
y console.writeline("{0}_____{1}",elemento A,elemento B)
pero el problema estaba en el indexoutrange entonces, pense si realmente se puede manipular la linea del output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto debería servirte:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList() { "A", "A", "A" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList() { "B", "B", "B", "B" };
// Determinas cual es el tamaño maximo de los arrays para usar de limite en el for
int tamMax = lista1.Count > lista2.Count ? lista1.Count : lista2.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < tamMax; i++) {
    /* Antes de imprimir el valor de cada array compruebas de que
     * no se pasa del límite y si se pasa del límite simplemente
     * imprimes un espacio vacío
     * */
    if (i < lista1.Count)
        Console.Write(lista1[i]);
    else
        Console.Write(" ");
    // Esto es solo para separar las columnas
    Console.Write("\t");
    /* Realizas la misma comparación que con la primera lista
     * pues no siempre sabes cual de las 2 es las larga
     * */
    if (i < lista2.Count)
        Console.Write(lista2[i]);
    // Imprimes el fin de línea
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar el sgte código:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList() { "A", "A", "A" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList() { "B", "B", "B", "B" };

var l1 = lista1.Count;
var l2 = lista2.Count;
var maxL = Math.Max(l1, l2);

for (var i = 0; i < maxL; i++)
{
    var x = i < l1 ? lista1[i] : ' ';
    var y = i < l2 ? lista2[i] : ' ';
    Console.WriteLine($"            {x}         {y}");
}
```

Lo importante es que el `for` vaya hasta el máximo de las longitudes de las dos listas. Luego en cada iteración se verifica primero si la variable `i` está dentro del rango de `lista1` o `lista2`, de lo contrario a `x` o `y` se le asignará un espacio en blanco. Luego ya puedes usar un `Console.WriteLine` normal para imprimir la línea correspondiente.

> **Nota** Si no usas C# 6 o superior la línea del `WriteLine` la podrías cambiar por esta:

```
Console.WriteLine("            {0}         {1}", x , y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, el uso de `ArrayList` en C# esta depreciado practicamente, se remonta a los tiempos donde no existian los genéricos en el lenguaje. Te recomiendo que utilices `List<T>` que implementa `IEnumerable<T>` y ,entre otras ventajas, te permite utilizar Linq en la colección.

Aprovechando te voy a dar una solución a tu problema usando los métodos `Zip`, `Concat` y `Skip` de Linq, que es lo que yo usaría:

```
//Lo primero convierto los ArrayLists a List<string> para mejor manejo
List<string> l1 = lista1.Cast<string>().ToList();
List<string> l2 = lista2.Cast<string>().ToList();

//Unimos las dos listas
List<string> zipped= l1.Zip(l2, (l, n) => l + new string(' ',5) + n)
            .Concat(l1.Count() > l2.Count() ? l1.Skip(l2.Count) : l2.Select(x=> new string(' ', 6)+x).Skip(l1.Count))
            .ToList();
//Finalmente, imprimimos los elementos de la lista resultante
zipped.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
```

`Zip` une las dos colecciones descartando los elementos que sobran si uno tiene mas. Posteriormente le unimos con `Concat` los elementos que faltan de la colección que tiene mas elementos.